# What is the top level interface in go?

Tags: go

Or what is the interface that all types implement?
I'm looking for something like the `Object` class in Java.

Is it possible for me to make my own kind of "Root" interface?

Comment: I think that there is no such thing as `Object` from java in golang, and the main reason is that golang enforces composability and not inheritance, anyway in general is a bad idea to add things to the global environment... also you should expand your question with the problem that you're trying to solve...

Comment: There wasn't a real problem. It was a curiosity question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any type that implements all the methods listed in the interface implements the interface.

The empty interface, `interface{}`, lists no methods. Therefore, all types implement it.

There is nothing "top level" about it however. Interfaces (although they can embed) do not have a hierarchical structure. The empty interface is simply a normal interface with no requirements.

Comment: That's what I was thinking in terms of making a "root" interface. I just wasn't sure how to put it.